# Update Database if change in Google Calendar Event

Tags: asp.net, google-calendar-api

I am creating app in ASp.NET for Google Calendar. I am getting one problem like if i have created a meeting into Google calendar using my application and after that i manually deleted that meeting from Google calendar, and i am again creating a meeting on the same time then it is showing busy because i am have an entry in my database because i am manually deleted the meeting from Google calendar. so is there any other procedure of getting the notification if there is any change to our event on Google calendar...

```
 Channel channel = new Channel();
 channel.Id = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();               
 channel.Type = "web_hook";
 channel.Address = "https://www.translitepc.net/Notification.aspx";        
 Channel ch1 = service.Events.Watch(channel, "hjain@scheduleonce.com").Execute();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Calendar API now supports [push notifications](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/push). You can use these to monitor changes to the calendar and keep the database synced up.

Comment: Thanks Jay for your reply. Do they have any client library for this or i have to do this by sending and receiving HttpRequest and HttpResponce

Comment: you should be able to use any of the Google API Client Libraries: https://developers.google.com/discovery/libraries

Comment: Hi, Now i am trying to use the client API for push notification but i am getting the problem while creating a watch resource. I am specifying my code below. Please look in to that. 
Channel channel = new Channel(); 
channel.Id = "01234567-89ab-cdef-0123456789ab"; 
channel.Type = "web_hook"; 
channel.Address = "http://www.translitepc.net/Notification.aspx"; Channel ch1 = service.Events.Watch(channel, "hjain@translitepc.net").Execute();

Comment: Yippi.. i have created a Watch request and getting a proper response. for this we have to set the OAuth_token property for this. Now how can i check it in my local that if i manually change any thing on Google Calendar then i should get the response Because in our code we have to specify our domain name with the specific page name to which we want to redirect the response.

Comment: Hi,
Thank for you reply. if i get the request header values on my webpage then how can i come to know that what are the events have changed over this calendar. As in request header it is setting up below mentioned parameters
X-Goog-Channel-ID: 4ba78bf0-6a47-11e2-bcfd-0800200c9a66
X-Goog-Channel-Token: 398348u3tu83ut8uu38
X-Goog-Resource-ID:  ret08u3rv24htgh289g
X-Goog-Resource-URI: https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/my_calendar@gmail.com/events
If i have changed the Summary and event time then how can i retrieve it because it is not passing any event ID.